# Jquery changing images on on click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have a problem with my click changing image, i have database messages , every message has a status 0 or 1 , from my code o have to click on status image and it will change, its changes BUT only for the first Message. When i click to other message status it not changes but changes only for the first status. how can i go this run!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$('.imageCheck').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
$("#bg").attr('src',"/application/admin/img/tick.png");  
});    
});

    </script>
```

```
                                            <th>Status</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                foreach ($users as $user):

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$user['id']?></td>
                    <td>                                                      
  <div class="imageCheck"><img id="bg" src="<?php echo $img_path;?>publish_x.png" name="statusCheck" value="0" />
                                                   </div>                                                     
                                            </td>
```

Comment: And try to stay away from PHP short tags.

Comment: I believe that `<?=` shorttags are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `#bg` in the your message control. In event handler use `find` to get nested `bg` element.

```
$('.imageCheck').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).find("#bg").attr('src',"/application/admin/img/tick.png");  
});
```

Comment: would recommend changing the #bg to .bg so that you don't have multiple ids that are the same

Comment: agree that it should be changed. but even with multiple elements with the same id code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Because an ID can (or rather should) only exist once in the DOM. jQuery is only changing the first element that matches the selector `#bg`. Try using a class instead:

```
<img class="bg" />

$('.bg').attr('src', '...');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids are supposed to be unique on a page.  Since you are looping you are going to have multiple imgs with id bg, so only the first one works.

as BenM states change it to .bg also update your code to find the exact image below the div

```
$(".bg", $(this)).attr('src',"/application/admin/img/tick.png");
```